# How to check the running time of my two different process in a single program

Tags: performance, algorithm

Here's the structure of my program

```
while(oneMoreTime){
  if(condition1)
    processA
  else
    processB
}
```

Now, for the first time, ProcessA runs, always. And once it is run, some data structure is built, alongside, that helps me in speeding up the process. 
Now under some condition and different inputs, processB will run.

Now, processB can not run, before ProcessA has run atleast once.

I want to know, by how much has the speed been improved, when processB gets executed than when processA is executed?

I am working with C and on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can record the time in the Process A and B, in C you can do this:

```
#include<time.h>
void ProcessA (...) {
   struct timeval starttime, endtime;
   gettimeofday(&starttime, NULL);
   ...
   ...
   gettimeofday(&endtime, NULL);
   printf("%f\n", 1000000 * (endtime.tv_sec - starttime.tv_sec) + endtime.tv_usec - starttime.tv_usec)   //
}
void ProcessB(...) {
   just like ProcessA
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a profiler, such as AQTime, to track and record the actual execution times of your processes so you can then analyze them.

Comment: I was thinking I could print the time just before and after ProcessA, and similarly for Process B. And check out the difference? Will that work? also, how do I print time in C?

Comment: +1 I use AQTime for just this purpose, and it handles multi-threading pretty well, although time spent in locking mechanisms often needs to be ignored / interpreted carefully.